# vim search for \\ not \

Tags: search, vim

I editing a latex file into html and I want to change all `\\` with a `<br />` -tag.

```
:%s@\\@<br />@g
```

Vim uses the first character after the :%s as delimiter so that not a problem. 
But I keep getting all the single `\` in my search just as as `\\`. I'm guessing that the first `\` is mapped to something but I don't no what or how to fix it.

And if I instead search do

```
:%s@\\\@<br />@g
```

I get `E59 : invalid character after \@` and `E476 Invalid command`.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question to mark up your backslash characters because they were being interpreted as escape characters by Stack Overflow. However, I'm not sure whether the `<"br />` is a typo or deliberate, so I left it alone. Is there supposed to be a double quote it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to replace all occurrences of two backslashes with `<br />`? If so, you need to escape both backslashes:

```
:%s@\\\\@<br />@g
```

A backslash is interpreted as an escape character that pairs up with the next character to indicate something special. For example, `\t` is used to indicate a tab character. To specify a backslash itself, you need two backslashes, so if you want two backslashes consecutively, you need to enter four.

Comment: thank you I was under the impression that  \ worked at the whole string and thought that I somehow remapped it.